# HTTP Error 500.23 - Internal Server Error

Tags: .net-4.0, iis-7.5, asp.net-4.0

Hi im trying to deploy my ASP:NET Web Site on the network in Windows 7 Enterprise
im getting this Error:

```
HTTP Error 500.23 - Internal Server Error
An ASP.NET setting has been detected that does not apply in Integrated managed pipeline   
mode.
```

I made some search like changing the the application pool from "Integrated" to "Classic".
it didnt realy help i become another Error:

```
HTTP Error 404.2 Error - Not found
ISAPI- and CGI-Restrictions
```

Can any one help point me in the right direction?

Comment: The issue is likely related to httpHandler configuration.  Classic ASP.NET and Integrated are configured differently in your web.config.  That setting can be changed on the IIS App Pool, but bare in mind that those options differ between versions of IIS.  What version of Windows Server are you using?  If it is 2003 or before Integrated Pipeline is not available.

Comment: sorry Windows 7 enterprise

Answer (score 32):

Add into web.config for HTTP Error 500.23 - Internal Server Error
An ASP.NET setting has been detected that does not apply in Integrated managed pipeline
mode.

```
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
  </system.webServer>
```